# How to insert a duplicate item at an index of an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

I use Angular 6 . I need to create a duplicate element in FormArray. I need to create method `createACopyAtIndex(indexNumber: number)` so that when one passes `indexNumber == 3`, then a duplicate element is created and assigned index of 4. The new array will have two duplicate elements: 3 and 4. I tried this

```
createACopyAtIndex(indexNumber: number) {
  console.log(indexNumber);
  var myArray = <FormArray>this.invoiceForm.controls['test'].value;
  this.invoiceForm.controls['test'].patchValue(this.getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex(myArray, indexNumber));
}

// this method returns a new array newArr
// this new array contains two duplicate elements: indexNumber and indexNumber + 1  
getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex(arr, indexNumber) {
  var temp = arr[indexNumber];
  var newArr = arr.splice(indexNumber, 0, temp);
  return newArr;
};
```

But nothing happens. No error. No changes

Comment: What is `getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex` supposed to do? The second parameter to  [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is the number of elements to be removed from `arr`

Comment: I'm just trying to create a copy of the new array because I try to `patchValue`. Yes I read splice. It looks like it should insert new element in the middle of aray as I want. Please help

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want but try `arr.splice(indexNumber, 0, temp)`

Comment: Sorry I added `0`. I had it removed because I tried to use `insert` also which didn't work. Yes splice has three arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) neither returns a new array nor the old mutated array. It reutns  deleted items from `arr`. In your case, an empty array

If you want to return a new array with a duplicate at the index specified, you can can take a copy of the original array using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Then use `splice` to insert at the index specified. Then, return the new array

```js
function getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex(arr, indexNumber) {
  var newArr = arr.slice();
  newArr.splice(indexNumber, 0, arr[indexNumber])
  return newArr
};

console.log(getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex([0,1,2,3,4], 2))
```

Another option is to `slice` the 2 parts of the arrays and insert a new item at the index and merge them using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const getDuplicatedArrayAtIndex = 
  (arr, i) => [...arr.slice(0, i + 1), arr[i], ...arr.slice(i + 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you this works. It looks like `patchValue` doesnt accept bigger arrays so i have to figure our patchvalue